# Initializing a Jagged Multidimensional Array from Text File

Tags: java, jagged-arrays

I have a question about initializing a jagged array from a file.

So, I want to create a jagged array.  Normally I would initialize it like so:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args]){
        String[][][] string = {{{"A", "1"}}, {{"B", "2"}, {"C", "3"}}, {{"D", "4"}, {"E", "5"}, {"F", "6"}}}
```

Now, suppose I have a file named array.txt that contains only one line which is just the right side of the initialization statement like below:

```
{{{"A", "1"}}, {{"B", "2"}, {"C", "3"}}, {{"D", "4"}, {"E", "5"}, {"F", "6"}}}
```

Now let's say I create a method called filetoString() that reads the file array.txt and returns that line as a string like the incomplete code I have below:

```
public class Test{
    public String fileToString(){
        \\method body
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Test test = new Test();
        String string = test.fileToString("array.txt");
```

What I want to know is whether there is a existing mechanism by which I can initialize the array from a string in a way similar to the last line in my example below.

```
public class Test{
    public String fileToString(String filename){
        \\method body
    }

    public String[][][] stringToArray(String input){
        \\method body
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Test test = new Test();
        String string = test.fileToString("array.txt");
        String[][][] strings = test.stringToArray(string);
```

If push comes to shove, I can make it work using for-loops and String.split(), but I figured I'd see if there was something already out there that I was missing before I went that route.  Many thanks!

Comment: Not within the standard Java library. There may be parsers out there but you can't ask for third-party resource recommendation on StackOverflow. Be very careful with the parser you write - remember that strings may contain double quotes and curly braces. `StreamTokenizer` might help.

Comment: Your content almost looks like JSON, so maybe consider using that format instead.  Or, you could just serialize your jagged array and write it out to file.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I'll look into it.